# How to append new and overwrite existing to SQL from PySpark?

Tags: sql, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-sql-server

So I have a table in an SQL database and I want to use Synapse (PySpark) to **add new records and overwrite existing records**. However in PySpark I can either use overwrite mode (which will delete old records that I am not pushing in the iteration) or append mode (which will not overwrite existing records).

So now I wonder what the best approach would be. I think these my options;

**Option A**: Load the old records first, combine in PySpark and then overwite everything. Downside is I have to load the whole table first.

**Option B**: Delete the records I will overwrite and then use append mode.
Downside is it requires extra steps that might fail.

**Option C**: A better way, I did not think of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `delta-lake`.

Answer (score 0):

Spark drivers don't really support that.  But you can load the data into a staging table and then perform a MERGE or INSERT/UPDATE with TSQL through pyodbc  (python) or jdbc (Scala).